# Converting text field with date to a date formatted field

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, date

I have a column with dates formatted like this:

```
July 14, 2015 11:02
```

How can I convert this to a DATE format for easier querying? (I don't necessarily need the time, if that makes it easier?)

EDIT
[image: Looks ok, but I'm still seeing an error]

EDIT 2
The month isn't being calculated correctly

[image]

Comment: This appears to be in date/time format already.  How are you using it or what is the problem? (there are not 3 underlying data types of Date, Time , & Date/Time.  Under the hood there is only Date/Time. You can choose how much you want to use or display...)

Comment: It was taken from my DB and is currently in General format. Any attempt to switch that to DATE, TIME does nothing at the moment.

Comment: The import from DB is messing up the type. If they data is in e7, then in another cell use =DATEVALUE(E7) this should show up as a number. Then convert it to date type.

Comment: Thanks, I read that solution elsewhere but it's not working. It just comes up as #VALUE!. Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you doing the inport from the DB? Also,  In a cell type (do not use copy/paste) the exact "July 14, 2015 11:02".  Does excel recognized it as a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your value in cell **A1**, this formula will isolate the date part:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)
```

by discarding everything after the last space *(the time part)*

To convert this to a **true date**, use:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1))
```

[image]

To do this conversion "in-place" would require a macro.

**EDIT#1:**

To find any "junk" characters in your data, place a sample date in cell **A1**.  then in **B1** enter:

```
=MID($A$1,ROW(),1)
```

and copy down.  then in **C1** enter:

```
=CODE(B1)
```

and copy down.  You should see:

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

Given your data in **A1**, this formula:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1)+2,4)
```

will return the year *(2015)*.  <strike>This formula:</strike>

```
=LOOKUP(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1),{"January","February","March","April","May",",June","July","August","September","October","November","December"},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
```

will return the month *(7)*.  This formula:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

will return the day *(14)*.

Putting this all together:

```
=DATE(--MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1)+2,4),LOOKUP(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1),{"January","February","March","April","May",",June","July","August","September","October","November","December"},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}),--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

This formula avoids regional sensitivities associated with *DATEVALUE()*.

**EDIT#3:**

As you discovered, the month array must be **sorted**, so use this for the month:

```
=LOOKUP(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1),{"April","August","December","February","January","July","June","March","May","November","October","September"},{4,8,12,2,1,7,6,3,5,11,10,9})
```

and this is the "final" formula:

```
=DATE(--MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1)+2,4),LOOKUP(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1),{"April","August","December","February","January","July","June","March","May","November","October","September"},{4,8,12,2,1,7,6,3,5,11,10,9}),--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

Edited to remove a space in the formula (Edits must be 6 char, hence this description)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The first line you've given me is working, but the second is returning an error

Comment: @DavidSigley  You may have non-visible **junk** characters in the data............I will update the post to show how to find them.

Comment: @DavidSigley  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and got the same results as you. However, it's still causing an error. I added a screenshot in my question

Comment: @DavidSigley  The only thing I can think of is the problem may be related to the date/time **system settings**

Comment: There are a lot of ways to get this problem . To help diagnose, (1) how are you getting the data from the DB into excel. (2) what happens if you go to an empty cell and manually type in the date exactly as it appears. Does excel recognize it as a date?

Comment: @bvaughn  EXCELlent suggestions!

Comment: @DavidSigley  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly, I can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: @DavidSigley  You are quite welcome.......this is of value to me as well.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed a funny bug with the month digit. Check out my edit, I have provided a screen grab

Comment: @DavidSigley  You are correct, I'll make a correction in a bit.........it might need a sort within the month array.........

Comment: @DavidSigley  See my **EDIT#3**